# WPF display command line options

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line

I need to add command line options to my WPF project, what I currently have sort of works but its not very nice. I need a more professional looking solution.

To write start and stop i do the following:

```
AttachConsole(-1);
Console.WriteLine("Start");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("Stop");
```

Which produces the output:

```
C:\Work>TestWriteCLI.exe -h

C:\Work>Start
Stop
```

There are several things wrong with this:

1. After i run the exe a new line is created with `C:\Work>` in it, I don't want this, i want it to print "Start" directly to the console.
2. After "Stop" is displayed, the program just waits there, waiting for "Enter" to be pressed, I don't want that either, i just want it to exit.

This is the output I am trying to achieve:

```
C:\Work>TestWriteCLI.exe -h
Start
Stop
C:\Work>
```

Other similar questions here have provided solutions I don't like, for example, I don't want to be creating new console windows. I have a console, i want it to run it that console not open a new one, display things, then close it and be back in my original console.

I also don't want to change my project to be a command line project.

My project is a WPF project, it should handle command line options in the normal way a command line project can, using WPF methods if possible.

Your help in this is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AllocConsole()` from `Kernel32 assembly` and to close console you can use `FreeConsole()`.

Import methods in your class

```
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
public static extern void AllocConsole();

[DllImport("Kernel32")]
public static extern void FreeConsole();
```

and use them this way -

```
AllocConsole();
Console.WriteLine("Start");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("Stop");
FreeConsole();
```

Comment: That method opens a new console window from my current console window, something i defiantly don't want to do. What happens with your solution is i run my exe from the command line, then a new cmd window opens where start and stop are displayed, then the new window closes and i am back in my current cmd window.

Comment: I didn't get that WPF project running in console window. So why not to have a Console project then?

Comment: The project is a GUI project which additionally has a secondary way to access it from an engineering team visa the command line interface. Perhaps i am missing something?  What are the implications of changing it from a windows application to a console application?

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, just run the executable with the `start` command with `/W` or `/Wait` as option, as documented [here](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

```
C:\Work>start /W TestWriteCLI.exe -h
```

For the second problem, add following line at the end of your code:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```